# Dynamic Jquery table constructed using ajax response data on textbox's each keyup event, not showing data of last ajax response (last keyup)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using ajax to fetch row data for a table based on the input entered in a textbox.

In my case, pincode input '1000' fetches 10 location rows and input '10007' fetches one row.

Following is the js code

```
 $('#pincode').keyup(function(event){
    var currentElementId = $(this).attr('id');
    enterlocation = document.getElementById(currentElementId).value;
    var len = enterlocation.length;

    if (len != null && len > 2 && event.which != 8) {
    var lastRequestTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();
        $.ajax({
            type : "GET",
            url : "/abc.htm",
            cache : false,
            contentType : "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType : 'json',
            data : {
                searchKey : enterlocation, lastRequestTimeStampSent : lastRequestTimeStamp},
            beforeSend : function() {
                $("#mytable").remove();
            },
            success : function(response) {
            var locations = response;
            var sentTimeStamp = parseInt(lastRequestTimeStamp, 10);
            var recievedTimestamp = parseInt(locations[0].requestTimeStamp, 10);
                $("#mytable").show();
                var locations = response;

                if (currentElementId == "pincode") {
                    $("#div1").append('<table id="mytable"></table>');
                }
                if (currentElementId == "city") {
                    $("#div2").append('<table id="mytable"></table>');
                }
                if (currentElementId == "street") {
                    $("#div3").append('<table id="mytable"></table>');
                }


                if ((sentTimeStamp == recievedTimestamp) && locations != null && locations.length > 0) {
                    $.each(locations, function(index, location) {
                        var locationRow = '<tr id="locationRowId'+index+'">' +
                        '<td>' +    
                        '<input type= "hidden" id ="hSugAddrLine1'+index+'" name ="hSugAddrLine1'+index+'" value="'+replaceNullwithBlank(location.addressLine1)+'">' +
                        '</td></tr>';

                        if ($("#mytable").children().length == 0) {
                            $("#mytable").append(locationRow);
                        } else {
                            $("#mytable").find('tbody:last').append(locationRow);
                        }
                    });
                }
            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("@Error");
                console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
            },
            complete : function() {
                $("#mytable").show();
                //$("#mytable").table("refresh");
            }
        });
    }

});
```

As I enter 10007 swiftly in the input box, what I get in the table is the response data for the pincode '1000' in most cases or response data for pincode '100' in some cases.

But when I enter '10007' slowly in the input text box, I get the correct ajax response data in the table as meant for input '10007'.

It appears to me some slow rendering issue. As mentioned, input '1000' response data is larger than that of '10007', so I think previous ajax call larger data is rendering on table even after next ajax call response is rendering. Being new and naive for jquery and ajax, I am quite brainstorming here. Help please!

Comment: AJAX calls are asynchronous. There's no guarantee that the one you start first will also get the first response from the server.

Comment: As a side note: Why you are removing `$("#mytable")` in `beforeSend`?

Comment: @Barmar Thanks Barmar. I never actually gave much heed to what AJAX stands for. Now I'll remember!

Comment: @Satpal Because I want to use a single common table in multiple div elements. User will be interacting with multiple div elements, one at a time though, each of those div elements are invoking the same table only. I want one single id table throughout my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling your server too fast... every keyup.  That will cause problems with any kind of heavy use.  What you may want to do is set a timer when a keyup event occurs, then when the timer is called, execute the AJAX call.  Set the timer for something like 1 second so that after a key has not been pressed for 1 second, the call is made.  This will reduce the extra calls.

Additionally, it wouldn't hurt to assign a timestamp id to the ajax call which is returned by the server with the results so that you can use only the last-sent AJAX call in populating your results.

Comment: You gave a very good insight into this scenario. I'll be considering the 1 second wait time to avoid flooding the server with the less useful requests. I'll also find how to fetch server time stamps to use them as Ids. Thanks to you.

Comment: No, no... don't fetch the server timestamp.  Send it from the browser and store that timestamp as the last timestamp sent... then just return it back to the browser from the server (unchanged), so that the browswer can compare the returned result timestamp to the expected last timestamp and only use results which match the last-sent call.

Comment: I see. I'll surely make use of this to improve the application. Thanks for the great enlightenment.

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother again, I have updated my code with the implementations but it's not working as expected. The table is still showing the data of second last ajax response rather than of the last one.

Comment: I am able to match the time values in the if condition but still afterwards the table got populated with old response.

Comment: It looks like it's because you have `var lastRequestTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();` within the function call.  Outside of all of your code, put `var lastRequestTimeStamp` and then just before the AJAX call, put `lastRequestTimeStamp = new Date().getTime();` -- that will keep the variable scoped globally.

Comment: Though soon followed by keyup only I'm stamping the time, don't know what's exactly going wrong. Your tip did work. I'll give a thought. Thanks a lot to you.